# MySQL syntax error for converting and formatting a date

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a line of code in MySQL. I am attempting to write the following line of code into a select statement that I already have and that works.  I have a comma both before and after the line to handle the field prior to this and after this.  The support_due_date field is a date field.

```
ISNULL(DATE_FORMAT(support_due_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '01/01/1900')  as support_due_date2
```

I'm getting a syntax error.  The support_due_date field has some null values and some date values.  I am wanting to format the field to have a M/D/YYYY format and if the field is Null change it to 01/01/1900.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using version 5.2.47 if that helps.

Comment: It looks like you want [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead of [`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)—although using "magic" values like this is, in general, a *very bad idea*.  Why not keep `NULL` in the resultset and detect/handle appropriately from within your application code?

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL()` by itself merely evaluates to true or false based on the argument passed; I believe your syntax error is due to attempting to pass 2 comma-separated arguments to that function. What you're actually looking for is, I think, something more like `if(isnull(support_due_date), '01/01/1900', date_format(support_due_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) as support_due_date2` .

The documentation for control flow statements (including `if()`) is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

That said, eggyal makes a good point about magic values in their comment to your question - imho there is a time and a place for both approaches, just something to consider.

Comment: uh, ok http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Comment: Thanks it was indeed IFNULL(), the following line of code did the trick:        IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(AC.support_due_date_c, '%m/%d/%Y'), '01/01/1900') AS support_due_date3  @Azim  Thanks to both of you!